# How to install WebKitGtk on Webfaction shared hosting server?

Tags: non-root-user, gtk, hosting-services, webkit

I would like to build simple NodeJS REST API that uses WebKitGtk to print HTML to PDF (this is the start, I getting more ideas).

So I managed to bring it up locally on my Debian Stretch dev laptop using:

1. Node,
2. Express and
3. libwebkit2gtk-4.0-dev (apt install) and node-webkitgtk (npm install) packages

Next I wanted to make it run on Webfaction hosting, so I logged in.
I compiled Cmake with --prefix=$HOME and... I hit the wall...

In webkitgtk-2.17.4/Tools/gtk folder there is [install-dependencies](https://github.com/WebKit/webkit/blob/master/Tools/gtk/install-dependencies) script that does not run without sudo...
How can I get over that obstacle and make WebKitGtk binary available to my local Node JS instance?

Answer (score 0):

Not possible as webfaction does not give you sudo root access. If they would, this would compromise the security garantee  of their server as others are making use of the same server (as it is shared hosting.....).